# How to assign a variable in XSLT and then use it in message flow/pipeline pair in OSB

Tags: variables, xslt, xquery, soa, osb

This query relates to OSB and xslt . I want to do some complex logic in xslt and then assign the resultant value to a variable . Now I want to use this variable after the xslt transformation action/stage . So in other words  how to assign a variable in XSLT and then use it in message flow/pipeline pair in OSB. pls help me ...thanks in advance . ..

Answer (score 1):

Use the Assign action. In xpath/xquery/xslt part call your XSLT. Its result will automatically get assigned to the variable defined in the assign action.